# error 1045 sqlstate 28000

Tags: mysql

```
 code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
    errno: 1045,
    sqlState: '28000',
    sqlMessage: "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)",
    sql: undefined
```

i have done everything possible:

- create new User
- grant permissions and all

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: There is no username being passed 

Comment: var connection = mysql.createPool({
     host: "localhost",
     user: "root",
     password: "password",
     database: "elites_1",
     port : "3306"
   })

Comment: every info is correct cos i can log in mysql root user...
i use ubuntu 22.04

Comment: The `root` user cannot be connected to by non-sudo operations. You will need to create an admin account, grant it proper permissions, and connect the software to that.

Comment: | GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `elites_1`.* TO `admin`@`%`
var connection = mysql.createPool({
     host: "localhost",
     user: "admin",
     password: "password123",
     database: "elites_1",
     port : "3306"
   })

Comment: code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
    errno: 1045,
    sqlState: '28000',
    sqlMessage: "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES)",
    sql: undefined

Still getting same Error

Comment: `%` is for external connections, `localhost` is used for local connections, and your error message is still showing an empty string where the username should be 

Comment: now working changing this % to localhost